# High Hardware Interrupt level on Windows Server 2003 (VM)

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, troubleshooting

I have a rather loaded Windows 2003 server. It's mainly loaded with IIS instances (about 6 or 7 w3wp processes) and some sharepoint stuff. The machine was P2V-ed from a real host and now resides on a much more powerful host under Windows Server 2008 as a Hyper-V guest. 2 Xeon 3.0 processors are emulated with 4 GB for the machine (the host itself is 8-cored with 16 GB). No more guest VMs reside on the host for now.

The problem is performance. The server is rather highloaded and consumes 60-70% of CPU, memory is not an issue. But I'm confused that 25% of CPU are consumed for Hardware Interrupts. Using kernview, I can see that intelppm is making the most of them. My question is - what can be the reason of that? Can I turn off intelppm through the registry, will the server work? I'm a little afraid to experiment on a production server and need some advice.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there might have been some problems with this before: [Virtual PC Guy Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2005/10/24/484461.aspx) - Note that Ben is suggesting disabling the driver in the registry, and that MS was researching automatically disabling this.  This might just be a remnant of your P2V migration.

Comment: Yes, I saw that blog, just wanted to know if someone has done it already to be sure there aren't much problems with turning it off... I can't afford much downtime for that server.

Comment: Get your self a maintenance window this weekend and try it.  The driver is used to write microcode to the CPU, so you shouldn't have any issues with it disabled.